# How can I undo the effects of reprepro update?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, repository, reprepro

On a private Debian package server, I accidentally did a `reprepro update` without the `--restrict` option, which updated all packages. Not realizing this, I then created a new distribution and populated it with all those updated packages.

How can I undo the mistake? For example, can I use `reprepro copy` to copy all packages of an older, correct distribution over to the new distribution? How can I undo the changes to the database?

References:

- http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/reprepro.1.html
- http://www.red-bean.com/doc/reprepro/manual.html#propagation
- https://serverfault.com/questions/489504/using-snapshots-with-reprepro-to-enable-rollbacks